# What method is used to integrate $\sqrt{t^3-t+1}$?

Tags: integration

I have tried to use integration by substitution and have tried $2$ different $u$ substitutions but I can't figure it out.

Comment: What $u$ substitution have you tried?

Comment: @kennytm He probably started with $u=t$ and didn't worked :)

Comment: You can't integrate it with usual functions.

Comment: This would involve elliptic functions (at least).

Comment: Maybe using Weierstraß' elliptic function $\mathfrak p$.

Comment: Maybe try $t = ku+l$ and select k and l in a linear equation system to make it a square.

Comment: The [integral](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%5Csqrt%7Bt%5E3-t%2B1%7D) looks complicated.

Comment: @mathreadler: the original polynomial has three simple roots (one real root and two complex conjugates), so no substitution like that can make it a square. The discriminant of $x^3-x+1$ is $-23\neq 0$.

Comment: You could move one of the roots to 0 which would allow you to factor down to a $\sqrt{u}\sqrt{u^2+au+b}$ and proceed by some other method. Maybe integration by parts combined with Hermite square root approach.